# Using decorators with Python Slack API

Tags: python, slack-api, python-decorators

I tried to create a simple decorator to use with the Slack API to make further coding, to improve functionality later much easier and more organized (say, in the future, I wished to include a new function/command that I wanted the bot to do)

But it's not working as I expected. Let me explain, here's my code (I have left out large chunks of code, such as instantiation, token, etc. to keep the question brief and illustrate the salient points) It includes a simple function which is supposed to output a message in the Slack channel:

```
class Bot(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        # Bot's user ID in Slack: value is assigned after the bot starts up
        self.starterbot_id = None
        # Declare constants
        self.RTM_READ_DELAY = 1 # 1 second delay between reading from RTM
        self.EXAMPLE_COMMAND = "do"
        self.MENTION_REGEX = "^<@(|[WU].+?)>(.*)"

    def startup(self):
        #Startup the client
        if slack_client.rtm_connect(with_team_state=False):
            print("Slack Bot connected and running!")
            # Read bot's user ID by calling Web API method `auth.test`
            self.starterbot_id = slack_client.api_call("auth.test")["user_id"]
            while True:
                command, channel = self.parse_bot_commands(slack_client.rtm_read())
                if command: 
                    response = self.command(command)
                    self.handle_command(response, channel)
                time.sleep(self.RTM_READ_DELAY)
        else: print("Connection failed. Exception traceback printed above.")

    def handle_command(self, response, channel):
        """
            Executes bot command if the command is known
        """
        # Default response is help text for the user
        default_response = "Not sure what you mean. Try *{}*.".format(self.EXAMPLE_COMMAND)

        # Sends the response back to the channel
        slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, text=response or default_response)

    def command(self, func):
        """
            Simple wrapper for bot commands
        """
        def wrapper_command():
            func()
        return wrapper_command

'''USAGE:'''
bot = Bot()
bot.startup()

@bot.command
def greet():
    response = "Hi there I am CodeMonkey"
    return response
```

What I was looking for was for the `greet()` command to get the bot to output `“Hi there I am CodeMonkey”`

The bot did respond, but not with a greeting. Instead it returns the object. This is the response I get from the bot in the channel:

```
CodeMonkey APP [11:40 PM]
<function Bot.command.<locals>.wrapper_command at 0x1083281e0>
```

I am still learning to use decorators and I feel that they will make coding my Slack Bot much easier and more organized, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect this decorator to do actually ????

Comment: My bad, I should have provided more explanation - I've edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the response you get is exactly what one would expect from this:

```
                response = self.command(command)
                self.handle_command(response, channel)
```

and this:

```
    def command(self, func):
        """
            Simple wrapper for bot commands
        """
        def wrapper_command():
            func()
        return wrapper_command
```

You call `self.command(...)` and  pass the result to `self.handle_command()`, `self.command()` returns a function, so `self.handle_command()` get this question as the `response` parameter.

You still didn't explain what you expected `command()` to do when used as a decorator, but I assume what you want is to use the decorated function as handler for a given 'command' (the parameter, not the function - hint: use distinct names for distinct things), ie `self.command('greet')` should call the `greet` function.

The very first thing you want is to use distinct methods for executing commands and registering them - so we'll name those methods `execute_command` and `register_command` - and while we're at it, we'll rename "handle_command" to "send_response" because that's what it's really doing:

```
def startup(self):
    #Startup the client
    if slack_client.rtm_connect(with_team_state=False):
        print("Slack Bot connected and running!")
        # Read bot's user ID by calling Web API method `auth.test`
        self.starterbot_id = slack_client.api_call("auth.test")["user_id"]
        while True:
            command, channel = self.parse_bot_commands(slack_client.rtm_read())
            if command: 
                response = self.execute_command(command)
                self.send_response(response, channel)
            time.sleep(self.RTM_READ_DELAY)
    else: 
        print("Connection failed. Exception traceback printed above.")


def execute_command(self, command):
    """
        Executes bot command if the command is known
    """
    # mock it for the moment
    return "this is a mockup"  

def send_response(self, response, channel):
    # Default response is help text for the user
    default_response = "Not sure what you mean. Try *{}*.".format(self.EXAMPLE_COMMAND)

    # Sends the response back to the channel
    slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, text=response or default_response)

def register_command(self, func):
    """
        TODO
    """
```

Now for the decorator part. Wrapping functions into other functions that will execute "around" the decorated one is a common use case for decorators, but that doesn't mean it's mandatory. technically, a "decorator" is just an "higher order function": a function that takes a function as argument and returns a function as result. Actually, the `@decorator` syntax is only syntactic sugar, so

```
@decorate
def func(): 
    pass
```

is just a fancier way to write

```
def func(): 
    pass

func = decorate(func)
```

and once you understand this you also understand that there's absolutely nothing magical here.

Now back to our `register_command` decorator. What we want is to store the argument (a function) so we can retrieve it based on it's name. This is easily done with a dict and `func.__name__`:

```
 def __init__(self, ...):
     # init code here

     self._commands = {}


def register_command(self, func):
    self._commands[func.__name__] = func
    # and that's all - no wrapper needed here
    return func
```

So you can now use

```
@bot.register_command:
def greet():
    return "Hello"
```

and then `bot._commands` should contain `'greet': <function greet @...>`.

Now for the `execute_command` method - well, it's quite straigtforward: lookup self._commands, if something is found call it and return the response, else return the default response:

```
def execute_command(self, command):
    handler = self._commands.get(command)
    if handler:
        return handler()

    # default:
    return "Not sure what you mean. Try *{}*.".format(self.EXAMPLE_COMMAND)
```

and we can now simplify `send_response()` since `execute_command` will take care of providing the default response:

```
def send_response(self, response, channel):
    # Sends the response back to the channel
    slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel, text=response)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! Really appreciate the explanation and your answer!

Comment: Hey there! Your code works like a charm! But now I wish for the new greet() function to accept a variable - how do I do that?

Comment: Just like for any other function, why ?

Comment: I did this: @bot.register_command def greet(variable): But I get an error: `TypeError: greet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'variable'`

Comment: Of course if you define your function to take an argument you have to pass this argument at call time - this is really CS101 level stuff.

Comment: Yes I know that - but the error is at `return handler()` part, which does not pass the variable on (which is obvious as it is `handler()`). This is the part that I'm trying to remedy. This will allow me to create new bot commands more easily

Comment: I've tried `*args, **kwargs` but that doesn't work either

Comment: " the error is at return handler() part, which does not pass the variable" => So what ? You of course have to modify the caller code to pass the param too. I'm sorry but I really don't get what you expected - there's absolutely no magic involved, if you want to pass something from the `startup` main loop to your handler functions you have to pass it down the whole call stack (which requires changing your functions signatures accordingly.